# Doing Supervised Learning where output should be a probability that adds to 1

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I'm trying to do some supervised learning on a dataset to surface which input is the most probable true input

[Example Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJqdk.png)

As you can see, each `INPUT_ID` only has one True `IS_TRUE_INPUT`. The goal is to obtain a probability of each input being the true input for each `INPUT_ID`.

I'm stuck as this does not seem like a normal classification problem and the probability of each input for each `INPUT_ID` should add up to 1.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### IF YOU HAVE SMALL NUMBER OF INPU_ID

Start with simples approach which is multiclass classification. Take the combination of `INPUT_ID` and `IS_TRUE_INPUT` as labels. The rest are your features. Convert categorical features to numericals (e.g. one-hot). Let the model decide.

I don't know why you need the probability distribution of predictions per `INPUT_ID`. You enter a new input and model gives you a probability of being member of a class. If I did not understand your use-case please comment and I will update.

Example for lines 77 and 78:

```
line 77 --> input = feature_set, output = {is_i171:1, is_i120:0, ...}
line 78 --> input = feature_set, output = {is_i171:0, is_i120:0, ...}
```

Depending on the model you use, probabilistic output will be a probability distribution over `is_i171`, `is_i120`, etc. e.g. a softmax decision function in NNs.

### IF THERE ARE SO MANY INPUT_ID

Embedd all data into a n-dimensional vector space. Calculate the mean vector of `TRUE` instances for each `INPUT_ID`. Foe a new query (input), calculate distances from each `INPUT_ID` mean vector and divide distances by sum of distances. Then you get a probability distribution of a new input being true for any of your input classes.